# I have a question about token 2022 program with migration

Tags: spl-token-program, associated-token-account

I wonder what happens to the existing ATA if I migrate from the existing token program to the token 2022 program.

1. If the migration is completed, can't use the existing ATA (before migration)
2. If the migration is completed, can't use the existing token (before migration)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very simple, there is no migration! All current SPL tokens belong to the SPL token program, and all token-2022 tokens belong to token-2022.

Two possible migration paths are:

- "upgrade" your tokens: create a new mint on token-2022, and pre-mint a bunch of tokens into an escrow. Using a protocol such as `spl-token-upgrade`, users can burn their old tokens in exchange for the ones
- "wrap" your tokens: create a new mint on token-2022, with mint authority controlled by a program. This program will receive old tokens into an escrow and mint new tokens, the "wrapping" process. At any time, users can "unwrap" their tokens by burning the new tokens to retrieve their old tokens

More information about token-upgrade at https://spl.solana.com/token-upgrade and more (limited) information about wrapping tokens at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/pull/3595